# Propylene Glycol to clean vinyl records

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I clean vinyl records with an ultrasonic record cleaning machine. Would propylene glycol be good to use as a surfactant in a 1 - 2 % concentration with distilled water?  Would it harm the vinyl record?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know nothing about cleaning records. However propylene glycol seems a poor choice to me. Propylene glycol has a low volatility, which means that it will not evaporate readily. I'd worry about it leaving a "sticky" layer on the record.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes I definitely would not want a residue that would be picked up by the needle!

Comment: http://www.audioheritage.org/vbulletin/showthread.php?19643-Record-Cleaning/page2 Suggests some formulations may have used propylene glycol. I’ll second that the Discwasher formula likely had it rather than isopropyl.

Comment: Hey MaxW, Had a thought (I do that every once in a while). The cleaning process calls for spraying the surfactant onto both sides of a record, brushing the surfactant into the record grooves, and then immediately placing the record in a 5 minutes ultrasonic bath.  Would the 5 minutes ultrasonic bath clean the sticky layer away from the record? Thanks again for your help. Thom Jones

Comment: Hey Jon Custer, Thanks for the link. Read it and there is talk of using Propylene glycol in cleaning records - as a solvent not as a surfactant. Would it work as a surfactant?  Thanks for your help. Thom Jones

Comment: Is there a reason to not use an actual surfactant, e.g., dishwashing detergent, in very dilute solution? I ask because it seems that cleaning the records is the main goal and propylene glycol has no necessary connection to that. Just curious!

Comment: Hi Ed, there is a solution  which is described as 98% distilled water and "1% - 2% Diol2 Propandiol 178, a type of propanol" but it seems fairly expensive. An article states this is the same as propylene glycol which is available on Amazon and much cheaper. The manufacturer states that 1% - 2% Diol2 Propandiol 178, a type of propanol is a surfactant.  The record cleaning solution is described as allowing the ultrasonic process to penetrate deep into the record grooves so that the microscopic explosions clean dirt  away much better than any other process.